# Eslint suddenly become an issue for my existing Vue Cli project

Tags: node.js, eslint

I had a single repository that I decided needed to be broken up.
It's a Vue CLI 2 project that has been working fine with Gitlab CI/CD until I started splitting it up.
There are two folders, one is the main vue project and the other is a folder of shared assets.
Prior moving repository Gitlab would happily run the process but now it's moved it's suddenly complaining about Eslint.

The first error was:

`No ESLint configuration found in [the shared asset folder]`

So then I started looking up this error and was convinced to run:

`eslint --init`

I went with the most barebones version of this which looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "overrides": [
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest"
    },
    "rules": {
    }
}
```

But the error for that is:

`Parsing error: ecmaVersion must be a number. Received value of type string instead`

Which is a complaint it makes about a bunch of files in the shared folder.

I can't find anything that solves this error, I've tried a few things but I'm generally frustrated because I don't really get why eslint is suddenly a problem or what it is even.

I'll probably be updating this ticket as I think about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the eslint configuration in my own project. There are more differences with yours, but perhaps you can change a few more settings to get it to work, so just give this a try I would say:

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "es6": true,
        "node": true,
        "browser": true
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaVersion": 2017
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended"
}
```

Comment: Oooh nice one - I'll give that a go!

Comment: When I did that - it started complaining about optional chaining and then I knew I was basically in a mire of questions I hadn't got answers to.  But thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I don't feel good about it but I made my problem going away by completely backtracking.

I had renamed my top level folders to `main` and `shared` when I copied the files over because it felt nicer.  I reverted this and everything else and the problem went away.

If I have time I will try and see if it was anything more than I realise but I'm wondering if either of these are reserved or magic, or if I had some other link to a file that had lost it's link.

But hey ho.  Lesson learned...or relearned.  Even the most mundane of changes is worth trying to revert.